# ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de centralizar los archivos/librerías que incluyo en mi programa?

Tags: php, html, buenas-prácticas

Acabo de instalar un certificado `SSL` en mi sitio web y en consecuencia las URL han cambiado de `http://example.com` a `https://example.com`.

Una de las consecuencias de esto es que muchas cosas no funcionan. Una de las más comunes es mi antigua inclusión de la librería jQuery: en muchos archivos yo incluía a librería en eh `header` con algo como esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Al instalar `SSL` me falla, porque la url que uso para la librería es `http`, y daba conflicto... aparte de ser una librería pre-histórica (ya vamos por la versión 3 :) ).

El hecho es que tengo cientos de archivos así, y ahora tengo que abrirlos uno por uno y actualizar la URL de la librería (menos mal que no son miles de archivos).

Para evitar situaciones como estas en un futuro, he imaginado que se podría centralizar la inclusión de archivos y librerías en un solo lugar, de modo que cuando haga falta cambiar algo, cambiarlo en ese solo lugar.

La solución que he aplicado ha sido la siguiente:

- crear una carpeta, a la cual he llanado `inc`, con los archivos que necesito incluir en diferentes partes.
- poner allí los diferentes archivos
- incluir cada archivo donde lo necesite

Por ejemplo, tengo:

```
inc
  jquery.php
```

En el archivo **`jquery.php`**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<?php
```

Ahora, donde yo quiera incluir la librería de jQuery, haré esto en el `header`:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Mi Título</title>
        <?php
              include ('../../inc/jquery.php');
        ?>
        <!-- Más cosas... -->    
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- contenido... -->    
    </body>

</html>
```

Así me está funcionando, pero dado que debo aplicar la misma práctica en mis otros archivos, quisiera saber, si es ésta una buena práctica (la verdad que usar código PHP en el `head` me resultaba chocante, no sé por qué), o si habría una mejor forma de centralizar la inclusión de archivos.

Agradezco cualquier alternativa, sugerencia, práctica... basada en soluciones reales.

Answer (score 2):

Mi conocimiento de PHP es nulo, pero puesto que pides buenas prácticas, te comento lo que he visto que es habitual en otras tecnologías web como puede ser Java (J2EE) o directamente en HTML5 como Angular o React:

En tu primera aproximación ya ves la ventaja obvia: puedes centralizar el código que repites en cada página y simplemente llamarlo cada vez que lo necesites, algo como:

- `import-scripts.php` donde tendrías tu Javascript (yo lo pondría en el body, tras cargar todo el HTML, pero ya es una cuestión de opiniones)
- `import-styles.php` donde tendrías las importaciones de CSS
- `nav-menu.php` donde tendrías el menú de navegación de tu página.
- `side-menu.php` Publicidad para el lado derecho, o listas de enlaces o cualquier cosa que necesites
- `footer.php` Enlaces de contacto, etc.
- ...

Pero incluso esto significa llamar a `include` en cada página varias veces (en cientos de páginas en tu caso).

¿Cómo podemos simplificar esto? **Invirtiendo la responsabilidad**, de un modo muy similar a cómo funciona la inyección de dependencias:

Crea una única página, (main.php, por ejemplo), donde importas todos los fragmentos, incluyendo la página que quieres mostrar:

[image: layout]

Tienes un archivo para cada componente, siendo uno de ellos especial: Los contenidos (contents) no se guardan en un único archivo, sino que según la petición que estés respondiendo incluirás uno u otro. Eso significa que tus cientos de páginas serían muy simples, teniendo directamente el contenido a mostrar y no preocupándose de qué necesitan.

En otras palabras, todas las peticiones serán servidas por la misma página, que mostrará un contenido u otro según sea necesario.

### Ventajas:

- Si te cansas de cómo se ve tu página, puedes cambiar todo el diseño de una sola vez, ya que cada página *contenido* no tiene ni CSS ni responsabilidad alguna sobre la navegación.
- Cualquier cambio de librerías no afecta más que a una página.
- No tienes que preocuparte del esquema si tienes que hacer una nueva página, simplemente creas el contenido y la incluyes en la lógica que elige qué página servir (que se puede hacer tan genérica como sea necesario)

En resumen: Es más [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas), ya que todo el código [*boilerplate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) está en un único sitio, por tanto pequeñas modificaciones globales no te obligan a modificar todo el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo estas haciendo mal, primero una buena practica es incluir los recursos sin http ni https

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Así el navegador resuelve automaticamente la ruta.

Y segundo, los ficheros link y styles estarian incluidos en un head.php y los ficheros js estarian en footer.php